# In SMTP with BINARYMIME format, can "Data" be used instead of "BDAT"

Tags: iis-7, smtp

I have an IIS 7 server that is rejecting the following command, however when I use a non IIS server this is accepted.

The Error is: `503 5.5.2 Body type BINARYMIME requires BDAT`

Based on my reading of SMTP CHUNKING the word "Data" should be replaced with "BDAT" and is the cause of the issue.  Can anyone confirm or help me understand what's wrong with this SMTP session?

```
09/10/2013 15:11:45.872 - Attempting to connect to host 10.10.10.10 on port 25, local bound address is (null)
09/10/2013 15:11:45.988 - Successfully connected to host 10.10.10.10   on port 25
09/10/2013 15:11:46.038 - < 220 *******************************************************************************************************************
09/10/2013 15:11:46.088 - ######## START OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.138 - > EHLO vmpro-PC
09/10/2013 15:11:46.138 - ######## END OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - < 250-smtp01.company.com Hello [10.1.1.1]
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-XXXA
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-SIZE 41009152
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-ETRN
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-PIPELINING
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-DSN
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-8bitmime
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-BINARYMIME
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-XXXXXXXB
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250-VRFY
09/10/2013 15:11:46.151 - 250 XC
09/10/2013 15:11:46.201 - ######## START OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.251 - > MAIL FROM:<moe@company.com> BODY=BINARYMIME
09/10/2013 15:11:46.251 - ######## END OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.264 - < 250 2.1.0  moe@company.com ....Sender OK
09/10/2013 15:11:46.314 - ######## START OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.372 - > RCPT TO:<moe@company.com>
09/10/2013 15:11:46.422 - ######## END OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.436 - < 250 2.1.5 moe@company.com 
09/10/2013 15:11:46.486 - ######## START OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.536 - > DATA
09/10/2013 15:11:46.536 - ######## END OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.547 - < 503 5.5.2 Body type BINARYMIME requires BDAT
09/10/2013 15:11:46.597 - CSMTPConnection::SendMessageA: An unexpected DATA response was received.
09/10/2013 15:11:46.697 - ######## START OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.697 - > QUIT
09/10/2013 15:11:46.697 - ######## END OF CHUNK ######
09/10/2013 15:11:46.710 - < 221 2.0.0 smtp01.company.com Service closing transmission channel
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding seems to be correct.  Quoting from [section 3 of RFC 3030](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3030#section-3):

> The BINARYMIME service extension can only be used with the
> "CHUNKING" service extension.

and:

> BINARYMIME cannot be used with the DATA command.  If a DATA command
> is issued after a MAIL command containing the body-value of
> "BINARYMIME", a 503 "Bad sequence of commands" response MUST be sent.
> The resulting state from this error condition is indeterminate and
> the transaction MUST be reset with the RSET command.

So it seems like the IIS server is compliant.  Presumably the other server is following [RFC 1830](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1830), which says that an error "should" be sent.